# Alternate to 'Except' in SQL with performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-except

I've a table TableA as in MS-Sql

```
 TrId   Status
 2345   3
  567   3
  567   0
 2345   0
   99   3
  778   0
```

Scenario is few TrIds have status as 3 as well as 0 , some have 3 only some 0 only. I need to find TrIds with status only 3. 
One of the ways to do is :

```
Select TrnId From TableA Where flgStatus = 3
EXCEPT
Select TrnId From Tablea Where flgStatus = 0
```

There are over 100 million records and i don't have enough time window for except, any alternative for this would be appreciative.

Comment: Which flavour of SQL? (PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, …?)

Comment: probably Postgress

Comment: @Ryan : Oops! it is Ms-squl . it is added now

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the combination `(TrnId,flgStatus)` unique?

Then you might switch to `EXCEPT ALL`, similar to `UNION ALL` which might be more efficient than `UNION` because it avoids the DISTINCT operation.

Another solution which accesses the base table only once:

```
Select TrnId 
From TableA Where flgStatus in (0,3)
group by TrnId
having MIN(flgStatus) = 3
```

Comment: That does not produce the desired result. If you change it to `MIN(flgStatus) = 3` though it does.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
WHERE flgStatus = 3
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT TrnId From TableA b Where flgStatus = 0 AND a.TrnId = b.TrnId)
```

This generally has better performance than `NOT IN`. A good alternate would be a join, see @ThomasG' answer.

Answer (score 2):

`EXCEPT` or `MINUS` is the right thing here. On a very large table it's however not optimal.

An alternative would be this

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA 
WHERE flgStatus = 3
AND TrnId  NOT IN
(SELECT TrnId From TableA Where flgStatus = 0)
```

Or even better, using `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` to avoid  the `NOT` which is a perf killer :

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA T3
LEFT JOIN TableA T0 ON T3.TrnId = T0.TrnId AND T0.flgStatus = 0
WHERE T3.flgStatus = 3
  AND T0.TrnId IS NULL
```

Edit : `NOT EXISTS` solution from Igor is also a good approach

Comment: I'll check the performance for this on tuesday and let you know if i've to hit the green check! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple `group by`:

```
select trnid
from tablea
group by trnid
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 3;
```

Whether this is faster or not depends on several things . . . notably whether or not you want to remove duplicates and what indexes you have on the data.  `NOT EXISTS` is likely to be faster if you don't care about duplicates, but the duplicate elimination requires work.

Comment: Well this one takes almost double the time of @dnoeth 's answer.

Comment: @EetSandhu  . . . You must have other statuses in your table then.

Comment: Yeah. 0,1,3 all all status types. i commented above just for sake of all. Otherwise it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For large dataset like yours, using the following query may give your desired result with reasonable performance -

```
SELECT ta1.TrId AS TrId
FROM dbo.TableA AS ta1
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableA AS ta2 ON (ta2.TrId = ta1.TrId AND ta2.[Status] != 3)
WHERE ta2.TrId IS NULL;
```

First, the self-join creates a table by arranging all the status (3 or 0, 1 etc) in the same row. The filter

```
 ta2.[Status] != 3
```

in the join clause puts NULL for the ta2.TrId (or ta2.*) if the Status is 3.

```
+------+--------+------+--------+
| TrId | Status | TrId | Status |
+------+--------+------+--------+
| 2345 |      3 | 2345 | 0      |
|  567 |      3 | 567  | 0      |
|  567 |      0 | 567  | 0      |
| 2345 |      0 | 2345 | 0      |
|   99 |      3 | NULL | NULL   |
|  778 |      0 | 778  | 0      |
+------+--------+------+--------+
```

Then the following filter is used to select rows where the NULL occurs.

```
WHERE ta2.TrId IS NULL
```

Since it is self LEFT JOIN, the left table has all the rows but NULL for right table values where the join criteria does not meet.

Comment: I'll check the performance of this one on Friday and let you know. if this works best for me or @dnoeth 's accepted answer.

Comment: I did not know earlier that you have status other than 0 and 3. So I have updated my answer and changed the filter of join clause a bit. I am also eager to see the comparison between the group by and join versions of this solutions for huge dataset.